# Contravariant type parameter for flow function?

Tags: javascript, flowtype, contravariance

I have two (more in reality) types, basically a basetype and a (multiple in reality) extended types. A function I have only operates on the base type parameters - it will only read the object and not update it. However it should accept any form of subtype and not have a problem.

So the function should be contravariant (correct me if I'm wrong I tend to mix those up sadly), I believe by saying the variable is read only it should work right?

```
type baseTy = {|
    id: number;
|}

type extendedTy = {|
    ...baseTy,
    extra: string,
|}

const dat: extendedTy = {
    id: 1,
    extra: 'test',
}

function getDoubleId(dat: $ReadOnly<baseTy>) {
    return dat.id * 2;
}

function doIt() {
    getDoubleId(dat);
}
```

However if I try above on [flow](https://flow.org/try/#0C4TwDgpgBARghgZwgFRFAvFA3gHwFBSFQCWAJgFxQB2ArgLYwQBOA3HjgL556iRQQAPYBCqkIpVBmz4iUAHQKAJAFEBcAMbAAPPCSoAfABoCRQcCZxKCc8SoBzY527qA9lWtRScYJTMixEmiYWCaEZJQAjMayZhaUAOTC1vHGXHgAZjRUmsRuUHYQwAAiLjQwADYQAJKkABRePlCKAEoQcKQA8lTlIDqIKCD6AJTYoVBMhTRMVJ7ecmRQAFRQAExsaZnZwLkzpC5VwLUjIbIFxaUV1XUNQ+tAA) I get the following error:

```
Cannot call `getDoubleId` with `dat` bound to `dat` because property `extra` is missing in `baseTy` [1] but exists in `extendedTy` [2]. [prop-missing]
```

Which seems weird to me: by stating the variable is readonly it should accept any "child" from the base type, right?

I've tried to add `$Shape<baseTy>` - To "remove" the exact marks around the base type but that has the same error....

Comment: Did you try to remove exact annotation from `baseType`? I think there is no point to have two exact annotations and to extend each other. One exact type is more then enough.

Comment: Agree, `flow` expects **exactly** (no other members allowed) `baseTy` to be passed into `getDoubleId`, so removing exact type is a solution

Comment: @Alex, yes but how how do I "remove exact" (Other than manually doing it) - for other reasons I cannot modify the `baseTy` definition, so I have to make a variant based on `baseTy` - basically "inexact baseTy` - which I thought `Shape` would do?

Comment: @paul23 I'd do it other way around: define the `baseTy` as not exact: `baseTy = { id: number, ...}`, and use [$Exact<baseTy>](https://flow.org/en/docs/types/utilities/#toc-exact) in places where it has to be exact.